# How to pass argument in Method_reference in Java 8 for user defined interface and method

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference, functional-interface

My code is something like this,

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface MathOperation2 {
    int operation2(int a, int b, int c);
 }

public class Method_reference_demo {
    private static int operate2(int a, int b, int c, MathOperation2 obj) 
    { 
        return obj.operation2(a, b, c);
    }
    private void Method_reference_demo01() 
    {       
    MathOperation2 mo2 = Method_reference_demo::operate2;
    mo2.operation2(2,3,4);
    }
}
```

is there anyway I can make it work by passing parameter through last two lines.
means below lines.

`MathOperation2 mo2 = Method_reference_demo::operate2;
mo2.operation2(2,3,4);`

I want above snippet as working code.
NOTE: I can't change any line of code except these two lines and want to use Java 8 Method reference.

Comment: It makes no sense. There is no object that actually implements `MathOperation2`. What is `mo2.operation2(2,3,4);` supposed to do? You need to explain why you can't modify the method,  and why you want to use a method reference.

Comment: Yes! it makes no sense. I just want to make sure. Can we replace lamda with method reference in these cases where interface and method modification is restricted.

Answer (score 0):

***Bottom line:***- You need to provide an implementation of the interface at some point in time to make use of it.

---

The line of code

```
MathOperation2 mo2 = Method_reference_demo::operate2
```

in an invalid declaration, since the signature of the `operate2` method

```
int operate2(int a, int b, int c, MathOperation2 obj)
```

expects a `MathOperation2` to be passed to the method as well.

Note, it can work if you change the signature to remove the last parameter, but that would make it inefficient as one would be better defining the abstract method of the interface itself which follows the same signature then.

---

> I can't change any line of code except these two lines

You can then rather define your interface as :

```
MathOperation2 mo2 = (a, b, c) -> {
    return 0; // perform the operation with a, b and c here
};
System.out.println(mo2.operation2(2, 3, 4)); // just to print the output
```

for e.g., to add three integers the representation would be:

```
MathOperation2 mo2 = (a, b, c) -> a + b + c;
System.out.println(mo2.operation2(2, 3, 4)); // would print '9'
```

---

(From comments) In terms of method references, the example would translate into something on the lines :

```
private static int operate2(int a, int b, int c) { // <<-- notice the method signature
    return a + b + c; // <<--  and a definition
}

private void Method_reference_demo01() {
    MathOperation2 mo2 = Method_reference_demo::operate2;
    System.out.println(mo2.operation2(2, 3, 4)); // prints '9'
}
```

Comment: Yes! with lambda it's possible.  I just want to use method reference instead of lambda .  Can we do it?

Comment: @JackDawson you need to define a similar method as that of your interface (refer to the section mentioned as a *Note*) and then that can be used as a method reference.

Comment: Why would removing the last parameter of `operate2` make it inefficient?

Comment: @Holger Oh maybe I portrayed it incorrectly, I didn't mean in terms of performance inefficient, but since OP already had a method `int operation2(int a, int b, int c)`, hence removing the last parameter from `int operate2(int a, int b, int c, MathOperation2 obj)` would just result in defining another method with a similar signature as that of the method in the interface. To what I *assumed* could just be an unwanted utility to define the lambda. (I think its review time, that you're back after a while. :))

Comment: Well, the static method `operation2` is entirely pointless as long as all it does, is invoking the same method on the incoming `MathOperation2` object, but it’s not clear what the method would become when removing that parameter. The only reasonable change would be what you’ve posted at the end of your answer, remove the parameter and change the code to do the actual operation.

Answer (score 0):

The method reference, `MathOperation2 mo2` should point to an implementation of the method, `int operation2(int a, int b, int c)` i.e. you can do something like

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface MathOperation2 {
    int operation2(int a, int b, int c);
}

public class Main {
    private static int operate2(int a, int b, int c) {
        return a + b + c;
    }

    private static void methodReferenceDemo01() {
        MathOperation2 mo2 = Main::operate2;
        System.out.println(mo2.operation2(2, 3, 4));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        methodReferenceDemo01();
    }
}
```

But it does not fulfill your requirement 100% as you have mentioned:

> I can't change any line of code except these two lines

On a side note, you should follow the [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) e.g. the method name, `Method_reference_demo01` does not follow the conventions; it can be named as `methodReferenceDemo01`.